# Hyperlink in PDF cannot open Excel files with macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, conversion, hyperlink

I am trying to convert a Word document (.docx) to a PDF. The .docx file has a few links to Word (.docx) and Excel (.xlsm NOT .xls) files. Both file types work when I click the hyperlink IN Word. However, when I save the file as a .pdf, ONLY the .docx files open.

I have deduced that it will not open due to the macros in the Excel files. (I did a trial run with converting a .docx to .pdf with links to .xls and .xlsm (with macros), and only files with macros are not able to open.

Please let me know if this can be fixed.

Comment: What version of Adobe products are you using to view these files? Have you looked at the Adobe forums where several of these questions have been posted and answered? https://forums.adobe.com/message/9758623#9758623

Comment: Thank you! this forum helped out tremendously! We decided to just add a hyperlink to the folder. Not ideal, but less risk it seems, and quite a bit easier. Thanks again music!

Answer (score 0):

.xlsm and other file types with active content (macros and the like) are blacklisted by Adobe. You can write exceptions to this policy to individual computers in the Registry, but if you want files to be able to be opened by a wide range of people on various computers, you will need to use either a different file type for the links, or use another method to link the files.